# Tomcat 9 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid keystore formatjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, tomcat9

I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid keystore format` in my log file each time I try to start Tomcat.

A full traceback of the error log is below

> 03-Aug-2023 16:01:52.411 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8433]]
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1050)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:554)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1045)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid keystore format
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:235)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1240)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:604)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:76)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1047)
> ... 13 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
> at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
> at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
> at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
> at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
> at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:217)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers(OpenSSLUtil.java:98)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
> ... 20 more

I have tried adding the keystoreType attribute with no luck and also changing the the keystore file from .jks to .pfk

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="norming.pfx" keystorePass="myKeyStorePass" proxyName="norming" proxyPort="443" keystoreType="PKCS12" />
```

Any help will be highly appreaciated

Comment: This is not programming or development, but: did you 'chang[e]' the keystore _file_ from jks to pfx/pkcs12 by converting the contents? Or did you only change its _name including suffix_? The name doesn't matter, you can name it 'abracadabra.pigglywiggly' and it works the same. Does `keytool -list -keystore norming.pfx -storetype PKCS12` work? If you have or get OpenSSL, what about `openssl pkcs12 -in norming.pfx -info -noout`? (If not, moving to superuser or possibly security.SX is probably best.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I realised that the `.pfx/jsk` files that were been generated using both openssl and Java's keytool were at fault or were not been properly generated.

I then proceeded to re-download the CRT files from the CA provider and used Microsoft Management Console (MMC) to generate the `.pfx` file.

This cleared the error above.

[Steps to generate the .pfx file using MMC.](https://knowledge.digicert.com/nl/nl/quovadis/ssl-certificates/ssl-general-topics/exporting-a-_pfx-using-mmc.html)